# Trying to use ofstream to write some basic text data

Tags: c++, ofstream

I'm just trying to write some text data out to a tab-delimited file. Here's the code. Name() and File() return CStringW, while ID() returns int,

```
ofstream myfile(file);

if (myfile.is_open())
{
    v::iterator i = begin();

    while(i != end())
    {
        myfile << i->Name() << L"\t" << i-ID() << L"\t" << i->File() << endl;
       i++;
    }

    myfile.close();

 }
```

But instead of getting the output I expect, the file looks like this

```
001554B00043F66840043F668001554F8
001555400043F6685440043F66800155588
001555F00043F6686000043F66800155638
001556B00043F6686240043F668001556F8
001557700043F6686680043F668001557B8
001558300043F6686800043F66800155878
001558E00043F6688560043F66800155928
001559C00043F6688720043F66800155A08
00155A700043F6689480043F66800155AB8
00155B200043F66810440043F66800155B68
00155BD00043F66811320043F66800155C18
00155C800043F66812840043F66800155CC8
00155D300043F66814040043F66800155D78
00155DE00043F66815360043F66800155E28
00155E900043F66815840043F66800155ED8
00155F400043F66816880043F66800155F88
001560180043F66817040043F66800156050
001560C80043F66817360043F66800156110
```

What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `wofstream`, which has the appropriate operators for `const wchar_t *`.

`wchar_t *` to `ostream` will use `operator<<(ostream &, void *)` as there's no operator for `wchar_t *`

EDIT: Use .GetString() on the CStringW's.

Comment: Just to be specific, the operator used is the member ostream::operator<<(const void *), the free function operator<<(ostream &, void *) isn't a part of the stdlib.

Comment: Using wofstream does help some, I now see the tabs in the output. But the strings still come through like this: 00155CC8 instead of the string value I expect. Also, the newlines don't appear to come through right either.

Comment: Actually, success! Including ,GetString() on the strings renders the correct results. Using (LPCWSTR) does as well. Thanks, problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

The way I've usually seen this handled is to cast the CStringW to an LPCWSTR, like this:

```
myfile << (LPCWSTR)i->Name() << L"\t" << i-ID() << L"\t" << (LPCWSTR)i->File() << endl;
```

Comment: And also, as stated in another answer, use `wofstream` instead of `ofstream` if you're using wide characters.

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing the raw pointer addresses of the `CString`s because they're treated as a `void*`.

[Documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/atl-mfc-shared/basic-cstring-operations?view=msvc-170#_core_converting_cstring_objects):

> To use a `CString` with `std::wcout` you must explicitly cast the object to a `const wchar_t*` as shown in the following example:
>
> ```cpp
> CString cs("meow");
> wcout << (const wchar_t*) cs << endl;
> ```